# How to match comma delimited value with other column in mySql

Tags: mysql

I have following two tables:

**user:**

```
+---------+--------------+
| user_id | skills       |
+---------+--------------+
|       1 | 1,2,3,5,4,14 |
|       2 | 1,2,3        |
|       3 | 3,4,5        |
|       4 | 1,2          |
+---------+--------------+
```

**pskills:**

```
+-----+--------+------+----------+
| PID | SKILLS | SPLI | status   |
+-----+--------+------+----------+
|   1 | 2,4    |    1 |          |
|   1 | 1      |    1 | required |
+-----+--------+------+----------+
```

I want to match values of **SKILLS** columns of table **pskills**. Such as if query is done with first row of **pskills** and join with user table then it will return User ID 1 because SKILLS 2,4 match with user id 1 only. How can i do this easily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Never store multiple values in one column!

You should normalize your tables like this

```
**user**
+---------+--------------+
| user_id | skills       |
+---------+--------------+
|       1 | 1            |
|       1 | 2            |
|       1 | 3            |
|       1 | ...          |
|       2 | 1            |
|       2 | 2            |
|         | ...          |
+---------+--------------+

**pskills**
+-----+--------+------+----------+
| PID | SKILLS | SPLI | status   |
+-----+--------+------+----------+
|   1 | 2      |    1 |          |
|   1 | 4      |    1 |          |
|   1 | 1      |    1 | required |
+-----+--------+------+----------+
```

Comment: It's one of SQL antipatterns from the book: jaywalking